# How to Make a PHP Variable Return Text Instead of Nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, variables

My code needs to see and use the text held in a variable:

I'm working on a WordPress plugin. One section of it needs to place text above the website's login form. If I just type in text as in the code below (return "My New Header Text";) it works fine and "My New Header Text" appears above the form.

```
// Add a CUSTOM MESSAGE to the top of the WordPress login form

function new_plugin_login_message( $message ) {
    if ( empty($message) ){
        return "My New Header Text";
    } else {
        return $message;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_message', 'new_plugin_login_message' );
```

But when I use a variable that includes the text, as in: (return "$MyNewMessage";) it won't work. Below is what I have. Even with lots of experimentation and Googling, I can't find a way for it to actually take the text stored in the variable and place it above the form. How do I make it see and use the text that is in the variable, "$MyNewMessage"?

```
// Add a CUSTOM MESSAGE to the top of the WordPress login form

function new_plugin_login_message( $message ) {
    if ( empty($message) ){
        return "$MyNewMessage";
    } else {
        return $message;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_message', 'new_plugin_login_message' );
```

This must be easy, but it eludes me. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You have to remove quotes: return $MyNewMessage;

Comment: Where is $MyNewMessage defined?  You aren't passing in the variable as a parameter and not using the global keyword.  Therefore, $MyNewMessage is not available to the function.

Comment: I've tried removing the quotes -- and just tried it again. That makes no difference -- it still won't show.

Comment: $MyNewMessage is defined earlier on. It comes from a record in the WP_Options part of the database. But I'm not sure what you mean by "passing in the variable as a parameter and not using the global keyword". Maybe that's my issue, but what does that mean?

Comment: Try to write: $MyNewMessage = "This is a test"; and then: return $MyNewMessage; without quotes. If you see the text your problem is in the code earlier that you are not show to us.

Comment: That was a good idea. I tried it and it still showed nothing, Interestingly, when I then changed that line of code to:  return print $MyNewMessage;  a "1" shows up where the title should  be. It sees a "1" - what does that tell us?

Comment: This is a scope problem.  Global variables defined in PHP are not available to functions.  You can pass the variable to a function, as in 'function(parm1, variable)'.  Or, you can use the global keyword.  In your case you can use 'return global $MyNewMessage;'

Comment: @MikeHickcox: FYI, you should address your comment to me, as I have done to you.  I never received any notice that you had replied to my comment.  I just happened to run across it now.  Did my comment help? Oh, print always returns a 1.

Comment: @CharlesEF: Thank you. When I use 'return global $MyNewMessage;' the script won't run. So I see I need to learn about global variables and parameters. I will study up on them and see if I can then make this work. I know it has to be able to work. I hope I can get back to you after I try that if I still can't figure it out.   - Mike

Comment: @MikeHickcox, Strange.  Try putting the 'global $MyNewMessage;' part right below the function name, before the if statement.  Then use 'return $MyNewMessage;'.  Any better?